# Setting precision for real types in Eiffel

Tags: double, precision, eiffel

In [Eiffel](http://eiffel.org), after doing some operations on a value of type `DOUBLE`, I get the result `1.9999999999999998`, while the expected result is supposed to be `2`.

I know that this is caused due to inaccuracies in floating point arithmetic. I need only two digits of precision (while using the `DOUBLE` type), and hence, if the number could be rounded off to two digits, I think the result would be `2` as expected.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3393178/5987698) question, but it only talks about displaying two digits, while I would like to know if there is a way to round off and store the value with two digits of precision.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**dcm** and **gobo** libraries (both included in standard EiffelStudio distribution under `contrib`) - provide classes `DECIMAL` and `MA_DECIMAL` that can be setup to store and manipulate numbers with specified precision. However, precision here is a total number of significant digits, not a number of digits after a decimal dot. If you need a specified number of digits after a decimal dot, use properly scaled integer types instead.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me how to use the classes? It says "Error: type is based on unknown class", when I tried to inherit from `DECIMAL`.

Comment: You need to add the corresponding library to your project (e.g., see the second part of a [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfXKFIPFdw8)), in the list of libraries it is listed as `decimal`. Also, note that `DECIMAL` is supposed to be used instead of `REAL_64`/`DOUBLE`, so it is not to be inherited, but used as a supplier.